# Align text inside a div of variable width

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divisions, each containing some text.
**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kPj8W/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="pillar1">
  <div class="pillar-text">
    <h1>aaaaaa aaaaa aaavvvvvvvvvvvv aaaabbbbbbbb bbbba aaaa</h1>
    <h2>Workshop</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pillar-text h1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 60%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in;
 }
```

[image]
[image]

But as in the screenshot, the text gets different *margin-right*'s for different divisions.

How can I solve this?

Comment: make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us please so we can test

Comment: OK.http://jsfiddle.net/kPj8W/

Answer (score 0):

`.pillar-text h1 {` that's what your CSS is titled as, however your text seems to be using h1 for one of them and h2 for the other.

either change them all to h1 to apply the right margin or define something for h2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

because you have `position:absolute`, your margin-right:30% is 30% of the window, not the div

```
.pillar-text h1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 30%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in;    
}
```